# Show that the recurrence relation $b_n \neq 0$ based on the information of another recurrence relation $a_n$.

Tags: inequality, recurrence-relations

Let's define one recurrence relation as:
$$
\begin{align}
a_0 &= 1 \\
a_1 &= x \\
a_2 &= x^2 + 2x \\
a_n &= x \left( a_{n-1} + 2 a_{n-2} + 3 a_{n-3} \right)
\end{align}
$$

Let's define an other recurrence relation as:
$$
\begin{align}
b_0 &= a_0 = 1 \\
b_1 &= a_1 = x \\
b_2 &= \frac{a_2}{2} = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + x \\
b_n &= \frac{x}{n} \left( b_{n-1} + 2 b_{n-2} + 3 b_{n-3} \right)
\end{align}
$$

I know already that if I choose any $x \leq -4$, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a_n \neq 0$.

**(Edit 1) What I have to prove:**
However from this information, I have to show that if I choose any $x \leq -4 n$, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $b_n \neq 0$.

Numerically this seems to be correct. But how should I prove this as both sequences are similar but the recurrence relation $b_n$ has non-constant coefficients whereas the recurrence relation $a_n$ has constant coefficients.

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Comment: @ElliotG I edited the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @thinkingeye: In case it helps, the generating function for $a_n$ is $G(z) = (1-xz \cdot (1 + 2z + 3z^2))^{-1} = 1 + x z + x (x + 2) z^2 + x (x^2 + 4 x + 3) z^3 + x^2 (x^2 + 6 x + 10) z^4 + O(z^5)$

Comment: Thank you for your Auswertung. But for $a_n$, I know already a lot. The problem is the transfer of these knowings to $b_n$.